# Find all Gaussian integers $α, β, γ$ such that $αβγ = α + β + γ = 1$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I tried to solve for this by assuming $α=a+bi$, $β=c+di$, and $γ=e+fi$, and explicitly solving this by equal $a+c+e=1$, $b+d+f=0$, and similarly for $αβγ=1$. Is there any other easier approach for this problem? I know $(1, i, -i)$  is a pair of solution. But is there any other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\alpha,
\beta,\gamma$ divide $1$, they are all units. The group of units is just $\{\pm 1,\pm i\}$. If any of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are equal from that list they cannot add to $1$ while simultaneously multiplying to $1$, and with three distinct $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$, there will always be a pair which are additive inverses, hence the third must be $1$, and the other two must be $\pm i$.

Comment: "If any of α,β,γ are equal from that list they cannot add to 1" - apart from the case (1,1,-1) which is easily checked to fail.

Comment: @Billy yes, I was reflecting on whether or not to notice that the answer posted much later looks suspiciously like a clone of mine, without the justification for why $\alpha+\beta=0$ and saw the comment show up. I agree it could be clearer, I was using the context that $\alpha\beta\gamma=1$ implicitly, but it should be made explicit.

Comment: This is a simple question, though not without its traps. Anyone else who answers it, no matter how much they try to avoid looking at the previous answers will come up with pretty much the same answer. They might make it denser than yours or more spoonfeeding than mine.

Comment: @RobertSoupe yes, this is why I didn't flag anything--I assume you just didn't read mine. Usually one doesn't post another copy of something which is fundamentally the same--it's generally good etiquette on MSE to read the other answers first, and post new approaches if you have one, or comment on an old one you think could be made more explicit.

Comment: So that's why sometimes my questions only get one lame answer that quotes Wikipedia! Then everyone else says "The question is already answered, nothing for me to do here, I'll move on to another question."

Comment: @RobertSoupe if you get wikipedia quotes, you can flag them as "not an answer" or "link only answer" and it will be deleted by the community. It's perfectly acceptable to post a real answer after a link only (and this is not uncommon). It's only two things which are fundamentally the same thing that give the appearance of reputation mining--usually that would only be done if a comment on another user's post requesting more details is summarily ignored.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. My recent Easter question first got a Wikipedia link as a comment, then there was an answer that didn't reference Wikipedia. Still, maybe everyone else who looked at that Easter question probably just assumed the only answer given so far is correct and well explained (which don't always go hand in hand).

Comment: And just for the record, your answer has not directly mentioned the norm function at any point prior to right now. And maybe Luis would point out he was the first to make anything of the asker's $\alpha = a + bi$, etc.

Comment: Thank you! I know it's a pretty easy question, I guess I just get stuck when trying to obtain a general answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring order, you have found the only possible solution. If $\alpha \beta \gamma = 1$, then it is a necessary but not sufficient condition that the norm function give $N(\alpha \beta \gamma) = 1$. This narrows the choices down to the units, 1, $-1$, $i$, $-i$ for each of the three variables.

But $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = 1$ means that $\alpha + \beta = 0$ (you could choose to take out a different variable but it won't change the end result). Therefore $\alpha = -\beta$ and $\beta = -\alpha$. And of course $\gamma = 1$.

So essentially this boils down to two possible solutions. $\alpha = 1$ and $\beta = -1$ works for the addition but not the multiplication: $\alpha \beta \gamma = -1$, not 1. This leaves the solution you have already found: $\alpha = i$, $\beta = -i$. This works because $\alpha + \beta = 0$ and $\alpha \beta = 1$, hence $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = \alpha \beta \gamma = 1$ as desired.

**EDIT:** This is how I got from $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = 1$ to $\alpha + \beta = 0$: I subtracted 1 from both sides to get $\alpha + \beta + \gamma - 1 = 0$. If $\gamma = 1$, then $\gamma - 1 = 0$ so "$\gamma - 1$" can be removed from the equation.

**2ND EDIT:** It seems perfectly obvious to me why at least one of $\alpha$, $\beta$ or $\gamma$ has to be 1. But since I don't want anyone to say I just copied off their answer, I'm going to prove this by brute force:

- $\alpha = \beta = \gamma \neq 1$ can't work because $u^n = 1$ with $u$ a unit other than 1 requires an even exponent or a doubly even exponent.
- $i, -1, -1$ doesn't work for the multiplication.
- $i, i, -1$ works for the multiplication but not the addition.
- $i, i, -i$ doesn't work for the multiplication.
- $i, -i, -i$ doesn't work for the multiplication either.
- $-i, -i, -1$ doesn't work for the multiplication either.
- $i, -i, -1$ doesn't work for the addition.

I don't need to hear criticism for this being inefficient but I do need to hear if I neglected to cover one or two cases.

Comment: Your second line does not justify why $\alpha+\beta=0$ is necessary.

Comment: And what if $\gamma\ne 1$?

Comment: That would be a game of mathematical musical chairs.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, but you haven't provided a complete solution without justifying why you can assume $\gamma=1$, you've just asserted this is the case.

Comment: Subtract 1 from both sides then set $\beta = 1$, or $\alpha = 1$. Then either $\alpha + \gamma = 0$ or $\beta + \gamma = 0$. I don't know, maybe I'm forgetting some simple detail but you think I never knew that detail in the first place.

Comment: I don't, it's just that you say "$\alpha+\beta+\gamma=1\implies \alpha+\beta=0$" but don't explain why that implication is true. It's a minor thing, but it should be amended so that the result follows from the assumption. Note that $\gamma=1\iff (\alpha+\beta+\gamma=1\implies \alpha+\beta=0$), so that what you're saying is that you can just assume $\gamma=1$ without a reason why that's so.

Comment: Maybe this'll make sense to me in the morning. Good night.

Comment: Thank you! It's very detailed and very easily understandable for a beginner like me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Taking norms we have $(a^2 + b^2)(c^2 + d^2)(e^2 + f^2) = 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ then the only solutions here are $\pm 1$ and $0$ for each factor. On the other hand, $a + c + e = 1$ and $b + d + f = 0$ put restrictions to be considered for the solutions $x + yi = (\pm 1, 0), (0, \pm 1)$ with $x = a, c, e$ and    $y = b, d, f$. The only solutions for the system are $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma) = (1, \pm i, \mp i)$, $(\pm 1, \mp 1, 1)$ (don’t forget $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}[i]$) and all the corresponding permutations that could be taken as equivalent.